# How to replace mail adresses in table input column with Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm quite new to PDI and currently facing a challenge where I have to replace mail adresses read from the email column of an incoming table (extracted by the Table Input step in Kettle) with other mail adresses.

e.g. user.test@example.com should become *abc[seq. number]@example.com*.

The goal is to "anonymize" the incoming adresses for further work with the data.

I currently have no solution for this and am hoping you guys have one. :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a Java class, or you can do the following, after the table entry, you create a sequence, then with the step, split rows you process the mail, takes as delimiter the @, in the configuration of the step you create two fields, One that will contain the initial part of the email and the other with the domain (gmail.com for example), then take the field of the sequence you created earlier, concatenate it with a constant @ (in the split rows you lose the symbol), And concatenate with field of the domain, in the end you will get 1@gmail.com, 2@hotmail.com, ect.solo are 4 steps I hope it helps you, greetings

Answer (score 0):

There exists a "Replace in String" step under the "Transform" section exactly for your case. 
Nevertheless, I recommend you to read some documentation first.

Comment: I already tried that, but I don't know how to insert the sequence number in the new mail adresses and make it increment for each row. Any ideas?

Comment: @MConan Use an "Add sequence" step after the "Table Input", then replace what is needed with a sequence field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just took the long way with adding constants, sequences and concatenating eventually.